# Drainage for sand box

Tags: concrete

Im building a large play area 370sqft. In the bottom I put tarp. I put small holes in key drainage spots. I'm thinking I should put a layer of pea stone on top of the tarp for better drainage then put the sand on top of the stones but it will cost a lot more. Is this necessary?

Comment: Any reason not to use landscaping fabric? That's porous by nature for allowing water through, and preventing stuff from growing up.  That's what we did for our sand box.  The ground *under* the landscaping fabric needs to drain well, and *that* you might amend further.  I can't imagine putting gravel on top of the barrier mixed with the sand would help much.

Comment: I've used landscape fabric before...eventually the weeds grow right thru it

Comment: Great comments that look like they might be fleshed out into an answer to this question.

Comment: @Mike, are you sure the weeds didn't grow in the medium on top of the landscape fabric?  We did have that problem. Or possibly multiple layers of fabric? Unless you really establish and maintain a grade, a tarp is going to end up with at least some pooling of water, and likely make the sand pretty funky.  Seriously doubt gravel above the tarp will help.  Speaking of funky and weeds, a cover will go a long way in preventing blown in weeds and animal ... uh... *contributions*...

Comment: The sand box I have is only 12'x12 and about 12" deep maybe 14" I put down river sand first if I would had to buy it I would have used pea gravel then fabric and on top the beach sand. Stuff will grow in the sand in the winter but it is not growing through the fabric and pulls out easily. It drains very well, I have to water it in the summer because it drains so well. +Matthew

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use a tarp. It will collect water despite your drainage holes and will result in mold, mud, insects, and other grossness accumulating. Use heavy landscape fabric (heavy enough that kids toys won't shred it) and forego the rock.

Or, put the rock under the fabric to allow drainage to the perimeter of the area, and allow drainage through your walls. You might consider fabric above *and* below the rock to isolate it.